# Intent Filter URL with # does not work?

Tags: android, android-intent

This is my path prefix

```
<data android:pathPrefix="/some.html#"/>
```

Android does not match this path when '#' is there in prefix. But when I remove the '#' in both URL and filter, it works. Does `#`
 have a special meaning ?

**EDIT**
`#` is a problem even when doing using path pattern

```
<data android:pathPrefix="/.*/"/>
```

Even this does not work when you pass `#` in the link but when the url does not contain `#`, it works.

Comment: Not sure if `#` has a special meaning but I think you should be able to use You can use `android:pathPattern="/some\\.html#\\."` to match the `#`.

Comment: tried this? <data android:pathPattern="/some.html\\#"/>

Comment: @MikeLaren : Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: @user1506104 : no, doesn't work

Comment: @MikeLaren : Do you want me to use it with path pattern specifically? I tried it with path prefix.

Comment: Yeah. The "pattern" seems to do regex matching while the prefix doesn't. But if you tested and it doesn't work then let's scratch my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> Use `&#35;` HTML Code for Hash 
>   [What's the HTML character entity for the # sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025171/whats-the-html-character-entity-for-the-sign)

Or

> \\# nullifies any special meaning to character

Comment: pathPrefix and pathPattern only support "*" and "." -> Referlink http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871065/match-app-and-not-appinst-with-androidpathpattern-working-on-an-intent-f

Comment: I know that. But I am not using # as a wild card. # is part of the url!

Comment: @Ashwin how did you solve the issue?